# Keep kubernetes logs of quicky terminating pods

Tags: kubernetes

I have an app in my cluster that starts automatically based on a metric and shuts down as soon as its job is down. Apparently the shutdown is to fast because my logging agents (DataDog agent and FluentBit) are not able to pick up the logs before the log file is deleted.

Is there a kubernetes deployment config that ensures the log stays around for a longer time period like and extra minute or so?

I'm using the CRI logging driver

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have the same problem with filebeat which harvests logs from Docker logging driver. I suppose your logging agents work the same way? They harvest the json logs files created by docker?

Comment: yes, the agents have a mounted volume to the logs files and basically tail them.

Comment: Maybe this [pod-meta-exporter](https://github.com/shirolimit/pod-meta-exporter#pod-meta-exporter) can be useful. Such approach mentioned in [https://github.com/fluent](https://github.com/fluent/fluent-bit/issues/2670)